# How to filter access table by ComboBox integer?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have connected my program to an access database file, and when I select the numbers in the combobox (1, 2, 3 etc.) I want to automatically fill the other textboxes in the form .. it works if it's a string .. for example if i select a string (e.g. name) in the combobox it automatically fills the other textboxes, but it doesn't work if it's an integer.

I know I must convert to int, but I don't know how because i have a query:

```
private void iD_FurnizorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string query;
        query = "select * from Furnizori where id_furnizor = '" + iD_FurnizorComboBox.Text + "'";
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            numeTextBox.Text = reader["nume"].ToString();
            adresaTextBox.Text = reader["adresa"].ToString();
            localitateTextBox.Text = reader["localitate"].ToString();
            judetTextBox.Text = reader["judet"].ToString();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I don't know where to parse the string to int.. thank you!!

Comment: Why is your `id_furnizor` column character typed? It seems wrong based on it's name. Change it to integer type and pass your integer value with a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Even if they are string, parse it to integer first and send it. And you probably never wanna use `throw ex` in your code. It resets the stack trace. And use using statement to dispose your connection, command and datareader.

Comment: Side note: `catch (Exception ex) {throw ex;}` fragment is totally useless.

Comment: Is it throwing any exception while filling the Textboxes? What you mean by "it doesn't work if it's an integer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `int.TryParse` to parse the string to int. You also have some issues like sql injection and not using the `using`-statement.

```
private void iD_FurnizorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id_furnizor;
    if(!int.TryParse(iD_FurnizorComboBox.Text, out id_furnizor))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("id_furnizor is not a valid integer: " + iD_FurnizorComboBox.Text);
        return;
    }

    using(var connection=new OleDbConnection("Connection String"))
    {
        try
        {
            string query = @"select f.* 
                             from Furnizori f
                             where id_furnizor = @id_furnizor;";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@id_furnizor", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id_furnizor;
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                numeTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("nume"));
                adresaTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("adresa"));
                localitateTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("localitate"));
                judetTextBox.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("judet"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;  // redundant but better than throw ex since it keeps the stacktrace
        }
    }// not necessary to close connection, done implicitly 
}
```

Comment: i tried the code, says "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0" instead. sorry, i'm really new to c#... i'm lost

Comment: @HEISENBERG: have you noticed that i've used a placeholder for the conenction-string? I don't know it but you.

Comment: @HEISENBERG: i'm glad that it helped. Consider to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which also closes it. And welcome at stackoverflow :)